# MySQL db management through FreePBX

Tags: mysql, pbx, asterisk

Is there an already prebuilt library for adding realtime DB management to an Asterisk Web-based GUI, like FreePBX ?

Comment: As I understand, you are using [AsteriskGUI](http://svn.asterisk.org/svn/asterisk-gui/branches/2.0/) and you want some rt database management fot it like addon?

Comment: You got it! Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I didn't use AstGUI that much, just tried it out for a day :D
but that sounds like a good idea for AsteriskGUI Developers to do next :D

Comment: In the meantime i'll have to do it by myself :) ,but it would be very nice if they could do it!